# Integration of myBB with website

Tags: mybb

I want my website and my mybb board to be connected. I Googled and made the integration, and I'm able to get a username id, as long as I specify their ID, but nothing happens when I'm using the function as explained.

What I'm trying to do is verify a connection of one to the forums, via my website, and then show their name.

Here's my code, as well as my attempts to get a username:

```
PHP Code:
define('IN_MYBB', NULL);
require_once 'forums/global.php';
require_once 'forums/class.MyBBIntegrator.php';
$MyBBI = new MyBBIntegrator($mybb, $db, $cache, $plugins, $lang, $config); 

$user = get_user($uid);

while ($forum_user = mysqli_fetch_array($user))
{
echo $forum_user['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
define('IN_MYBB', NULL);
require_once 'forums/global.php';

if(isset($mybb->user['uid'])){
echo "User Found: ".$mybb->user['usernmae']."($mybb->user['uid'].")";
} else {
echo "No user found";
}
```

MyBBIntegrator isn't even required. But the above code will check if the user is logged in, and display the username and userid. If not it will display No User Found. Hopefully this helps.